# What percentage of Ethereum addresses that currently have an ETH balance, also have DAO Tokens?

Tags: ether, the-dao

I read a comment elsewhere that insinuated that the population of DAO Token Holders was a tiny subset of the Ethereum community. My impression is that this isn't the case, but I have no way of knowing. I also have no idea of how to figure this out.

Ideally, data from ~June 1st (after creation period, before everything went down) to determine this, but I'll take whatever you can give me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**10.986%** of all accounts with ETH have DAO.

22873 dao holders / (201442 accts w eth +  6756 contracts w eth)  = 0.10986

All data from etherscan. TheDAO page has the DAO holders, then:

https://etherscan.io/accounts/a/8058

https://etherscan.io/accounts/c/271

*Edited since the etherscan page originally linked shows all accounts that ever had eth.*

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on ETHeREAL's answer (no need to upvote).

If we ultimately want to know approximately how many *people* hold both ETH and DAO, there are some flaws with any answer we come up with, which is why I asked the question in the way I did. However, it's worth noting:

1. 1 account != 1 person.
2. Percentage of ETH holders that are also DAO holders may be significantly higher that data shows as people may not have wanted to expose 100% of their ETH holdings to an account that held DAO. (thx auryn_macmillan)
3. ETH accounts with teeny, tiny amounts are included in dataset but if we assume these are accounts that once held ETH, and then moved to a new account but ultimately miscalculated gas, then we should exclude these from our dataset as well. It wasn't until very recently that Mist added the "Send All" functionality.  If The DAO had been around longer, or it was equally hard to "Send All DAO" as it is/was to "Send All ETH", then it might be okay. This also includes the `1 wei` accounts which are often used for verification or signing, not an actual holding account that would ever purchase DAO.

---

Regarding #3:

I'm making arbitrary cutoffs just too see what that range is. We will assume anything less than that balance is no longer an active account that could have ever invested in The DAO, or is accounted for in another account. (thx BokkyPooBah)

**balance > 0.0001ETH = 14.43%**

- [152216 accounts with ETH](https://etherscan.io/accounts/a/6089)
- [6289 contracts with ETH](https://etherscan.io/accounts/c/252)
- [22873 accounts with DAO](https://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO)

= .144304596 = 14.43%

**balances > 0.01 ETH = 19.78%**

- [109330 ETH accounts](https://etherscan.io/accounts/a/4374)

22873 / (109330 + 6289) = 19.78%

**balances > 0.1 ETH = 25.76%**

- [82482 ETH accounts](https://etherscan.io/accounts/a/3300)

22873 / (82482 + 6289) = 25.76%

**balances > 1 ETH = 35.59%**

- [57975 ETH accounts](https://etherscan.io/accounts/a/2320)

22873 / (57975 + 6289) = 35.59%

Comment: If we only include accounts with balances > 1 ETH, there are 57975 ETH accounts (https://etherscan.io/accounts/a/2320). Redoing the calculations 22873 / (57975 + 6289) = 35.59%

Comment: If we only include accounts with balances > 0.1 ETH, there are 82482 ETH accounts (https://etherscan.io/accounts/a/3300). Redoing the calculations 22873 / (82482 + 6289) = 25.76%

Comment: If we only include accounts with balances > 0.01 ETH, there are 109330 ETH accounts (https://etherscan.io/accounts/a/4374). Redoing the calculations 22873 / (109330 + 6289) = 19.78%